# The name doesn't exist in the current context - How to resolve?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I try to access a class that is not in the current namespace while I also added `using` for that class namespace but still receive an error.

There is an error that says:

> The name 'AddNewDataFile' doesn't exist in the current context.

[image]

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you receive The name doesn't exist in the current context, you can check for these options:

- Maybe you haven't defined a variable or member with that name in the scope.
- Maybe you misspelled an existing variable or member name.
- Maybe the namespace that defines that class is missing.
- Maybe your project needs to add a reference to the dll contains that type.

For more information and example see:

- [The name 'NNNN' does not exist in the current context (C#)](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mswinswdev/ms_csharp_name_does_not_exist_in_current_context.htm)