# I am having a problem opening an SQL Server Database in Visual Studio in C#

Tags: c#, connection-string

I am opening a Microsoft SQL Server Database in C# on Visual Studio. I create a new connection to the database using the following syntax:

```
using (SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection("Data Source=mssql.viewster.com.au;Initial Catalog=loanbillboard1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Loanbillboard1;Password="xxxxxx!")) ;
```

But when I try to actually open the connection it comes up with the error "The name 'connectionString' doesn't exist in the current context."

```
private void Window1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string QueryString = "Select * from User";
            using (SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection("Data Source=mssql.viewster.com.au;Initial Catalog=loanbillboard1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Loanbillboard1;Password=Stettin1953!")) ;
            {
                connectionString.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Diagnostics%   Database is Open");
            }
        }
```

`ConnectionString` is flagged as not existing in the current context.

The connectionString object should have been created by the using (`SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection` but Visual Studio is flagging it on the Open.

Does anyone have a working example of opening the Microsoft SQL Server from within Visual Studio like this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. You might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009273/the-name-doesnt-exist-in-the-current-context-how-to-resolve

Comment: You making SQL connection and not connection string. SQL connection uses connection string. But since name doesn't matter much syntax is ok apart from some mismatch in your solution and libraries

Answer (score -1):

I searched for the exact error text in Google and found an answer which was to upload and install the latest assemblies for Microsoft SQL Server in Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).